# How to add andthen() operator under condition or inside a loop Rx Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-kotlin

I'm trying to chain some rx operations under a condition but the andthen() inside the apply does not execute. Is this correct? operation returns a Completable. Android studio gives me the warning "The result of andThen is not used" in both andthen() calls.

```
operation.apply {
   if (true) {
      andthen(thisDoesNotExecute())
   }
}
.andThen(thisExecutes())
```

Same happens here, only doAnOperation(aList[0]) is executed, should I add a .subscribe inside the andThen()?

```
operation(aList[0])
    .apply {
        if (aList.size > 1) {
            for (item in aList.sublist(1, aList.size)) {
                andThen(operation(item))
            }
        }
    }
    .subscribe()
```

Comment: I'm not a Kotlin programmer, but you surely need something like `return it.andThen(...)` in `apply`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`andThen` returns a new instance with your transformation, it doesn't mutate the original source, so you have to use its return value if you want to take it into account.

`apply()` returns the instance on which you call it, so in your case it will return the initial `operation`, not the result of the `andThen()` transformation.

You should read up on [scope functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html) to understand which one suits you best. Here you want to return the result of `andThen()`, so you need a scope function that returns the lambda result, not the receiver. Then you can choose whether you want to have the `operation` object as `this` or `it` inside the lambda, which decides between `run` or `let`.

Let's go with `let` here:

```kotlin
operation.let {
    if (condition) {
        it.andthen(thisDoesNotExecute())
    } else {
        it
    }
}
.andThen(thisExecutes())
```

If you need this often, you could create your own extension function to encapsulate that.

You could also use an intermediate variable instead of course:

```kotlin
val intermediate = if (condition) {
    operation.andThen(thisDoesNotExecute())
} else {
    operation
}
val result = intermediate.andThen(thisExecutes())
```

For your loop, you could use `fold()` like this:

```kotlin
aList.fold(Completable.complete()) { acc, item -> acc.andThen(operation(item)) }
     .subscribe()
```

Or to stay really close to your initial approach without initial `complete()` element, you could `map` first and then use `reduce()`:

```kotlin
aList.map { operation(it) }
     .reduce { c1, c2 -> c1.andThen(c2) }
     .subscribe()
```